# How to convert ordinary java Color to IndexedColors

Tags: java

I am working in java 1.6 and I use the apache poi in order to generate xls stylesheets.
I am letting the user pick a color using jcolorchooser in order to style the cells.
The problem I am facing is the cellstyle's setfillforegroundcolor  of apache poi accepts only indexedColors value, how would I go about using the ordinary color object instead? or how about converting the color object into indexedColors?
or is there a better approach to all this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could instantiate an `XSSFColor` based on java.awt.Color, then call `getIndexed()` on that object to convert.  Not sure if there's a better approach overall - I'm not a POI library specialist- although the [javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/) seem to indicate that you can use `XSSFColor` throughout and the indexedColor is just for backward compatibility.  it might depend on what version of the POI library you are using.

```
Color selectedColor = myJColorChoose.getColor();
XSSFColor userColor = new XSSFColor(selectedColor);
myCell.setFillForegroundColor(userColor.getIndexed());
```

Comment: In POI 3.17 this constructor marked as TEST only: /**  TEST ONLY - does not know about custom indexed colors @param clr awt Color */  public XSSFColor(java.awt.Color clr).

Answer (score 1):

Although J Richard Snape answer is correct, it added additional apache libraries overhead. and I think it only fits xlsx files, I prefer to not go beyond xls so here is my solution:

just generate a custom color palette like so:

```
    public final void addColorToSheet(HSSFWorkbook wb, Color c, short index){
        HSSFPalette =wb.getCustomPalette();
        byte 
                red=(byte)(c.getRed()&0XFF)
          ,     blue=(byte)(c.getBlue()&0XFF)
          ,     green=(byte)(c.getGreen()&0XFF);
        palette.setColorAtIndex(index,red,blue,green);
      }

      public final CellStyle getCellStyleForColor(HSSFWorkbook wb,Color c){
            HSSFCellStyle style=wb.createCellStyle();
            short index = (short)(IndexedColors.values.length+1);
             addColorToSheet(wb,c,index);
             style.setFillForeground(index);
             return style;
        }
```

Usage:

```
             HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook();
             Row headerRow =sheet.createRow(1);
             headerRow.setRowStyle(getCellStyleForColor(wb,new Color(20,20,20));
               .....
```