# Change cell Background color depending on cell value

Tags: java

Using java program I store values in excel sheet. 
I want to change the background of the cell depending on the value, that the cell contains. So if a cell with value 12 has red color, the one with 13 must be darker red and if cell with value 1000 is green the cell which contains 1001 should be greener and so on.
 I cant use IndexedColors.RED.getIndex(), because it doesn't offer different degree from single color.

Comment: Do you write to a template workbook or do you create the workbook in Java and then write to it? If you have a template, then apply some conditioned formattings for it. Otherwise check out how to apply RGB values (and conditioned formattings).

Comment: reading and writing to excel are not native to java -- what library are you using to read/write wookbooks, and advice can be given from there ( IMHO the javadoc of that library will give you the answer as well ).

Comment: @deHaar  I am editing workbook, that I have created in previous methods, using  Apache POI

Comment: Please provide some code you have tried. How do you apply formattings and content to cells? Maybe it's just a `String` like `"rgb(" + rValue + "," + gValue + "," + bValue + ")"` that you have to put in your formatting.

Comment: @deHaar   I change the color  like that :
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
 style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
cell.setCellStyle(style);
it does work just with the colors defined in java and no degrees of color

Comment: the method "IndexedColors.RED.getIndex()" returns variable short, so I can't replace it by color (255,255,255)

Comment: Then you have to define your own colors in Java and apply those by using `getIndexed()`. [See this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032550/how-to-convert-ordinary-java-color-to-indexedcolors) here on stackoverflow...