# How to use colors not in IndexedColors for Apache POI XSSF Excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am looking at an excel sheet that I am wanting to duplicate and the only issue I am having is with colors. The colors I am looking to duplicate are `Blue, Accent 5, Lighter 40%` and `Light Green` from the `Standard Colors` section. I am looking at the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors) for using custom colors in an XSSF Workbook and it states that the way to do it is like this:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("custom XSSF colors");

XSSFCellStyle style1 = wb.createCellStyle();
style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
style1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

When I try to use `style1.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128), new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));` I get an error, since the only parameter that `.setFillForegroundColor()` only takes one parameter, and that is a `short` and not an `XSSFColor`.

Has anyone had any luck with this? I have been searching for hours and can't find anything that isn't 8 years old or doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032550/how-to-convert-ordinary-java-color-to-indexedcolors ?

Comment: @VladBochenin I have not, but it looks like he is passing a Color to XSSFColor constructor, which is now deprecated. Non deprecated constructors are (IndexedColorMap), (Color, IndexedColorMap), (byte[], IndexedColorMap) and (IndexedColors, IndexedColorMap)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash That answer suggests using IndexedColors, my issues is that the colors I am looking for are not in the IndexedColors Enum, so I would need to create my own custom colors.

Comment: What exact error you get using what `apache poi` version? Using current `apache poi 4.1.1` there is [public void setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-) in `XSSFCellStyle`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using current `apache poi 4.1.1` there is [public void setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-) in `XSSFCellStyle`.

The `XSSFColor` should be created using constructor [public XSSFColor(byte[] rgb, IndexedColorMap colorMap)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#XSSFColor-byte:A-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.IndexedColorMap-) since all other constructors are either deprecated or marked `TEST ONLY` or not usable for creating a custom color.

The `RGB` values for the needed color can be got from `Excel` by setting the color from the palette and then choose `Fill Color` - `More Colors` - `Custom`. Unfortunately `apache poi`'s [IndexedColors](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html) are no more exact the colors of current `Excel` versions. They are of version `2007`. So they also can be used but later `Excel` versions might show different colors then.

Complete example using current `apache poi 4.1.1`:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.DefaultIndexedColorMap;

public class CreateExcelXSSFCellFillColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  java.util.List<XSSFCellStyle> cellStyles = new java.util.ArrayList<XSSFCellStyle>();
  XSSFCellStyle cellStyle; byte[] rgb; XSSFColor color;

  //Your custom color #800080
  //create cell style on workbook level
  cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  //set pattern fill settings
  cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  //create the RGB byte array
  rgb = new byte[3];
  rgb[0] = (byte) 128; // red
  rgb[1] = (byte) 0; // green
  rgb[2] = (byte) 128; // blue
  //create XSSFColor
  color = new XSSFColor(rgb, new DefaultIndexedColorMap());
  //set fill color to cell style
  cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);

  cellStyles.add(cellStyle);

  //Light Green
  cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  rgb = new byte[3];
  rgb[0] = (byte) 146; // red
  rgb[1] = (byte) 208; // green
  rgb[2] = (byte) 80; // blue
  color = new XSSFColor(rgb, new DefaultIndexedColorMap());
  cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
  cellStyles.add(cellStyle);

  //Blue, Accent 5, Lighter 40%
  cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  rgb = new byte[3];
  rgb[0] = (byte) 155; // red
  rgb[1] = (byte) 194; // green
  rgb[2] = (byte) 230; // blue
  color = new XSSFColor(rgb, new DefaultIndexedColorMap());
  cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
  cellStyles.add(cellStyle);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  for (int r = 0; r < cellStyles.size(); r++) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
   row.setHeight((short)(20*20));
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("cell style " + (r+1));
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyles.get(r));
  }
  sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 20*256);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXSSFCellFillColor.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Why you're creating all the time new DefaultIndexedColorMap instead of reusing one per woorkbook?

Comment: how to return an indexed map from Workbook in modern POI (4.1.2)?

Comment: `cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor)` — there is no such method in modern POI. We can set it via Font, but it looks a bit ugly.