# Java- Apache POI XSSF - Custom RGB Cellbackground not working

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I want to use a custom RGB color (38,38,38) for my cell backgroundcolor.
For that I use this code:

```
IndexedColorMap colorMap = wb.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors(); 
XSSFColor customtablegrey = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(38,38,38), colorMap);
cellFormat1.setFillForegroundColor(customtablegrey.getIndex());
cellFormat1.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

But all I get is a black background. Why and how can I change it?
[image]

Best Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true. `IndexedColorMap` is useless for `XSSFColor`s. `XSSFColor`s are not indexed colors. In `Office Open XML` custom colors are stored as RGB directly in the XML. They are not stored in any kind of color map.

Setting `XSSFColor`s as fill foreground color to cell styles is possible using [XSSFCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor-) only. It cannot be set using `CellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(short fg)`.

So `cellFormat1.setFillForegroundColor(customtablegrey)` should work when `cellFormat1` is a `XSSFCellStyle`.

[How to use colors not in IndexedColors for Apache POI XSSF Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002274/how-to-use-colors-not-in-indexedcolors-for-apache-poi-xssf-excel/59005983#59005983) shows a complete example for how to use `XSSFColor` as cell fill color. Just tested using `apache poi 5.1.0` too.

[APACHE POI 4.1 : Set cell background color from hex code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594849/apache-poi-4-1-set-cell-background-color-from-hex-code/58603161#58603161) shows another complete example. Also tested and works using `apache poi 5.1.0` too.

Comment: Hm I get even if it is `XSSFCellStyle` an error: `The method setFillBackgroundColor(short) in the type CellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (XSSFColor)`

Comment: What `apache poi` version used?

Comment: I use  `apache poi V5.1.0`

Comment: Oh damn sorry I have two Formats and changed it only for Format2. Yes it works thanks!

Comment: @Muddyblack k: I have linked two complete examples which are tested and working.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry all working. After all the stuff i changed I didnt recognize I changed it to setFillBackgroundcolor. I am very grateful for your answer!